# How to sum values of each column and remove the column with lowest sum in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix and I want R to sum values of every single column and then remove the column with lowest sum. I know that colSums does it but how to tell it to remove the lowest sum?

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f
a   3   5   2   6   4   2
b   2   8   0   0   9   0
c   0   7   0   7   8   6
d   0   4   0   2   7   8
e   5   5   3   4   3   9
f   0   2   3   5   4   5
```

Answer (score 2):

We get the `colSums` as mentioned in the OP's post.  Then check which values of those are not equal to the minimum value of the `colSums`  i.e. `v1!=min(v1)`.  Use that for subsetting the matrix 'm1'.

```
 v1 <- colSums(m1)
 m1[,v1!=min(v1)]
```

Or if there are no ties for the minimum values, `which.min` can be used (as suggested by @A. Webb and @David Arenburg) that returns a numeric index and can be removed by `-`.  If there are ties for minimum values, `which.min` returns the column index of the first minimum value.

```
 m1[,-which.min(v1)]
```

Comment: `m[,-which.min(colSums(m))]`